# Как добавить в ClusterizedPlacemarkCollection маркер без анимации всех остальных маркеров (flutter)

Tags: flutter, yandexmapkit

Использую yandex_mapkit 3.3.3 flutter.
Мне нужно в группируемые маркеры ClusterizedPlacemarkCollection добавить или убрать маркер, но так что бы все маркеры не анимировались. Список маркеров неизменяемый, добавить новый в существующий не получается. При замене всего списка маркеров - есть анимация появления маркеры.
Не нашел как убрать анимация появления маркеров (placemarks) из ClusterizedPlacemarkCollection или добавить новый.

Подскажите, как добавить в список placemarks из ClusterizedPlacemarkCollection маркер без анимации всех остальных маркеров?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но насколько помню, добавление объекта в кластеризатор вызывает его пересчёт, потому все объекты просто обязаны перерисовываться заново. Если штатный кластеризатор Яндекса вам не нравится, придётся делать свой.